# Doesn't show window correctly compared to QtDesigner's window

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm creating a GUI application using PyQt5, I made the UI using QtDesigner and ended up with this result:

[image: QtDesigner Preview]

But this issue is that when I launch my application using Python, following the screen size I'm using, the application is not showing properly: on my laptop (from which I took the QtDesigner screenshot above), here is the result:

[image: Python view]
[image: Cropped side bar]

(The white part was just to make it more visible that the rectangle is not properly displayed)

As you can see, the left side bar is not showing properly on my laptop, but on a bigger screen, it shows perfectly so I assume that the size of the screen is the error factor but I don't see how I could fix it. Is there any options I have to make sure to use in order to not have the sizes issues?

Here is the code you can use to have a minimal reproducible example:

The code generated from QtDesigner is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'main_mreZokVTK.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.1
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1200, 800)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200, 800))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(1200, 800))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.drop_shadow_frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setObjectName(u"drop_shadow_frame")
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setEnabled(True)
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(2)
        font1.setBold(False)
        font1.setWeight(50)
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setFont(font1)
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setStyleSheet(u"background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 255), stop:0.972851 rgba(103, 103, 103, 255));\n"
"border-radius: 10px\n"
"")
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.drop_shadow_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.lateral_bar = QFrame(self.drop_shadow_frame)
        self.lateral_bar.setObjectName(u"lateral_bar")
        self.lateral_bar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 90, 781))
        self.lateral_bar.setMinimumSize(QSize(90, 781))
        self.lateral_bar.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 781))
        self.lateral_bar.setStyleSheet(u"background-color:rgb(20, 20, 20);\n"
"background-color:#000000")
        self.lateral_bar.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.lateral_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.lateral_bar)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.fonctions = QFrame(self.lateral_bar)
        self.fonctions.setObjectName(u"fonctions")
        self.fonctions.setMinimumSize(QSize(90, 691))
        self.fonctions.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 691))
        self.fonctions.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.fonctions.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.fonctions)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_4")
        self.Raffles = QFrame(self.fonctions)
        self.Raffles.setObjectName(u"Raffles")
        self.Raffles.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Raffles.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.btn_raffles = QPushButton(self.Raffles)
        self.btn_raffles.setObjectName(u"btn_raffles")
        self.btn_raffles.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 70, 163))
        self.btn_raffles.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 0))
        self.btn_raffles.setMaximumSize(QSize(1000, 8000))
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setFamily(u"MS Sans Serif")
        font2.setPointSize(1)
        self.btn_raffles.setFont(font2)
        self.btn_raffles.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.btn_raffles.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton {\n"
"   border-radius:8px;\n"
"   background-color:none;\n"
"   border:2px solid rgb(45, 45, 45);\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   background-color:rgb(20, 20, 20);\n"
"   border:2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255)\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.btn_raffles.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))

        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Raffles)


        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.fonctions)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.drop_shadow_frame)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.btn_raffles.setText("")
    # retranslateUi
```

And the code used to display the application is the following :

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import (QTime, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QPixmap)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QTimer
import sys
import PyQt5
from ui_main_mre import Ui_MainWindow



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the UI file, we cannot just guess what you did.

Comment: here is a repository containing the file obtained after the python translation of the UI using QtDesigner and the main file to show the application to provide a minimal reproductible example : https://github.com/realloulou/mre_ui

Comment: Please, include the code in the question (possibly, try to reduce its contents, for example by removing all buttons except one), as question should always be self contained, and relying on a repository (which is probably going to change in the future) would make the question difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're adding buttons to a widget (the QFrames) and without any layout set there. Using fixed geometries is almost never a good idea, and doing that in an UI that has other layout managers is almost always a very bad idea.
Remember, what you see on your screen is almost *never* what others see in theirs; also, Designer doesn't always show in its preview what the actual result will be. In your specific case, the problem is that when your code loads the ui, the buttons are actually a bit shifted, so their contents are partially hidden because of their parent size (a child widget cannot draw outside the parent's rect).

So, first of all, set a layout for all the QFrames that contain a button (and to any other widget that still has no layout), if your issue is ensuring that the buttons occupy the whole space available for their container, then set their horizontal and, most importantly, vertical size policy to `Preferred` (Qt buttons by default don't expand vertically).

Then, there are other issues with your implementation:

- the main widgets inside the central widget are "floating" (aka, fixed geometries), so set a layout for the central widget too;
- remove all size constraints of buttons, as they're unnecessary;
- avoid generic stylesheets, especially if set on parents; using [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) is always better, otherwise you might face unexpected behavior (especially from advanced/custom widgets);
- check that minimum/maximum sizes are consistent (the button icons have minimum sizes bigger than their maximum);
- be aware that Qt uses default layout margins and spacings depending on the current OS and style in use, so you must be careful with special widgets for which those aspects are important (the title bar, in your example); when in doubt, *explicitly* set those values in the layout properties (even if you're fine with the values set as default) and remember that every form in Designer can have default values for layouts from the "Form > Form settings" dialog (they are not visually applied in Designer, but they're respected when loaded from code);

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, could you be more precise on what a generic stylesheet is ? I assume that setting the stylesheet for a widget in order to choose the background color for instance is not needed if the parent widget already has the back ground color chosen in its stylesheet but I'm not too sure. Could you give me further explanations because the selector syntax (I think I should be using "*" as suggested on the link you provided in your answer) is not an option I found in the Set StyleSheet window in QtDesigner.

Comment: @louisab 1. yes, that's exactly what happens, Qt stylesheets (just like their web counterparts) always propagate the their children; see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213091/2001654) and read the documentation linked there; 2. the stylesheet editor only provides "shortcut" commands for properties, the selectors, due to their possible complexity, must be entered manually.