# PyQt - How to use the "setStyleSheet" method properly?

Tags: python, pyqt, styles

if I use the `setStyleSheet` method in order to change the style for a specific widget, the other ones placed inside it, changes their style, but I don't want it! I can bring you two example:

when I change the border/background color for a frame  (see the widgets placed inside it):

```
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
import PyQt5.QtCore as qtc
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import sys

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
 
        self.resize(520,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Treeview Example")

        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()

        self.frame1=qtw.QFrame()
        self.frame1layout=qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame1layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.frame1.setLayout(self.frame1layout)
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid; border-color:red; background-color:white") # I change the style for the main frame
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame1)
        
        self.frame2=qtw.QFrame()
        self.frame2layout=qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame2layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.frame2.setLayout(self.frame2layout)
        
        self.frame1layout.addWidget(self.frame2)
        self.ProgressBar=qtw.QProgressBar()
        self.frame2layout.addWidget(self.ProgressBar)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

or when I change the border color for a treeview widget (the scrolled treeview widget is became white):

```
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg
import PyQt5.QtCore as qtc
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import sys

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
 
        self.resize(520,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Treeview Example")

        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()

        self.treeview = qtw.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeview.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid; border-color:red") # it destroy the style of the objects inside the treeview widget!
        model = qtg.QStandardItemModel()
        rootNode = model.invisibleRootItem()
        
        section1 = qtg.QStandardItem("A")
        section1.appendRow([qtg.QStandardItem("A1")])
        childnode = qtg.QStandardItem("A2")
        section1.appendRow([childnode])
         
        section2 = qtg.QStandardItem("B")
        section2.appendRow([qtg.QStandardItem("B1")])
        section2.appendRow([qtg.QStandardItem("B2")])
        
        rootNode.appendRow([section1])
        rootNode.appendRow([section2])
        
        self.treeview.setHeaderHidden(True)
        
        self.treeview.setModel(model)
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.treeview)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

my question is, how can I change the style of a specific widget without modifying the style of the other ones?

###########
UPDATE:

in my first example, if I don't use the instruction `self.treeview.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid; border-color:red")` I realized that the progress bar widget doesn't expand as before. see this screenshot:
[image]

what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you to more carefully read the [style sheet syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) and [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) documentation, as everything is *clearly* specified and explained there:

> Style sheets consist of a sequence of style rules. A style rule is made up of a selector and a declaration. The *selector* specifies which widgets are affected by the rule; the *declaration* specifies which properties should be set on the widget.

Stylesheets are, by definition, *cascading*.

The stylesheet set on a widget is propagated on its children, those children *inherit* the style of the parent.

If you set a generic property like this:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

The result is that **all** its children will have that border: you only gave the *declaration* but without the *selector*, so a *universal* selector is used as implicit.

This is not just Qt, this is typical of CSS (from which QSS take their main concepts), and it works exactly as any other widget *styling* property: setting a font or a palette on a widget, propagates them to all its children.
The difference is that with stylesheets (exactly like standard CSS) you can use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

If you want to style the tree widget only, then use that class selector:

```
    self.treeview.setStyleSheet('''
            QTreeView {
                border: 1px solid; 
                border-color:red;
            }
    ''')
```

Comment: in my first example I have a frame inside another one. I have two questions. what is the right selector if I want to change just the style for the first frame? if I use the instruction `self.frame1.setStyleSheet("QFrame{border: 1px solid; border-color:red; background-color:white}")` the selector `QFrame` influences both of them. the second question is, why if I don't use the instruction `self.frame1.setStyleSheet(..)` the `self.ProgressBar` widget doesn't expand followind the layout specified (`self.frame2layout`)? there is a space on the right side..

Comment: The first answer is: use selectors properly. For instance, when you're using the same base class, use the `#objectName` selector (`self.frame1.setObjectName('topFrame')` and then `QFrame#topFrame {...}`. I don't understand your second question, you only see a space on the right, not on the left?

Comment: thanks for the reply musicamente, now I undertand. for my second question I attached an image and updated my topic. let me know.

Comment: I have the same issue if I change the styles only for the two frames using the instructions: `self.frame1.setObjectName('topFrame')`  `self.frame1.setStyleSheet("QFrame#topFrame{border: 1px solid; border-color:red; background-color:white}") ` `self.frame2.setObjectName('xx')``self.frame2.setStyleSheet("QFrame#xx{border: 1px solid; border-color:blue; background-color:white}")`

Comment: I've taken your first code snippet and added the lines above at the end of the `__init__`, and I don't see that behavior. I suggest you to do the same (take the code from the post, don't try to adapt it from what you have on your computer!) and check the results. We cannot compare code if we're not sure we're using the same code. Note that calling `self.frame1.setStyleSheet` automatically **overwrites** anything previously set on that same widget, so it doesn't matter if you commented the first `setStyleSheet` line or not.

Comment: you are right, don't see my last comment, just see what I wrote at the end of my post. if I don't use the instruction `self.treeview.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid; border-color:red")` the `self.ProgressBar` widget doesn't expand completely (there is an empty space on the right side). it means that whithout a style for the `self.ProgressBar` widget, it can't expand itself. how can  solve this issue? I can see this behavior in my real code too.

Comment: ciao. I chose you your answer as the right one but I still don't understand how to solve the issue exposed in my last question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not able to reproduce your issue.